# Uploadifive dynamically posting input variables

Tags: jquery, post, file-upload, input, uploadifive

The problem below is that when the function is initiated, of course, `MyInputVariable` is empty.

```
<?php $timestamp = time();?>
$(function () {
    $('#file_upload').uploadifive({
        'auto': false,
        'dnd': true,
        'checkScript': 'check-exists.php',
        'formData': {
            'timestamp': '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
            'token': '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>',
            'MyNumber': $('#MyInputVariable').val(),
        },
        'queueID': 'queue',
        'uploadScript': 'upload.php',
        'onUploadComplete': function(file, data) {console.log(data);}
    });
});
```

There must be a way to instigate `onUpload`, `onUploadComplete`, `onUploadFile` or something to update `formData`, but I am at a loss as to how to do that.

---

Please note that this is uploadiFIVE, not uploadify. The functions/methods differ significantly, and solutions will probably not apply to both.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After many hours of experimentation with misleading solutions on the uplodifive forum, this is the solution.

In your HTML anchor tag:

```
<input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" multiple="true">
<a style="position: relative; top: 8px;" href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadifive('upload')">Upload Files</a>
```

Change the anchor tag to:

```
<a style="position: relative; top: 8px;" href="javascript:uploadFiles();">Upload Files</a>
```

Completely eliminate the formData setting from the initial function call so it then looks something like this:

```
$(function()
{
    $('#file_upload').uploadifive(
    {
        'auto'               : false,
        'dnd'                : true,
        'checkScript'        : 'check-exists.php',
        'queueID'            : 'queue',
        'uploadScript'       : 'upload.php',
        'onUploadComplete'   : function(file, data) {console.log(data);}
    });
});
```

Than add this function:

```
   function uploadFiles()
   {
      $('#file_upload').data('uploadifive').settings.formData =
      {
         'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
         'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>',
         'MyNumber'  : $('#MyInputVariable').val()
      },
      $('#file_upload').uploadifive('upload');
   }
```

And whatever other variables you need to add.
Your input variables will now post on upload.

Comment: Any suggestions to make auto upload (auto=true)? it works only when auto is set to false and click on the link to call the upload function

Answer (score 5):

I think this is best anwser

[How to submit dynamic variables with uploadifive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19017530/how-to-submit-dynamic-variables-with-uploadifive)

replace this:

```
'formData': {
        'timestamp': '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
        'token': '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>',
        'MyNumber': $('#MyInputVariable').val(),
    },
```

by this:

```
'onUpload' : function(){
$('#file_upload').data('uploadifive').settings.formData = {
        'timestamp': '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
        'token': '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>',
        'MyNumber': $('#MyInputVariable').val(),
}},
```

and this is full code:

```
<?php $timestamp = time();?>
$(function () {
    $('#file_upload').uploadifive({
        'auto': false,
        'dnd': true,
        'checkScript': 'check-exists.php',
        'onUpload' : function(){
                $('#file_upload').data('uploadifive').settings.formData = {
                        'timestamp': '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
                        'token': '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>',
                        'MyNumber': $('#MyInputVariable').val(),
                            }},
        'queueID': 'queue',
        'uploadScript': 'upload.php',
        'onUploadComplete': function(file, data) {console.log(data);}
    });
});
```

Comment: Looks like a more correct jQuery example to me! Thanks!